# Running docker containers on a different drive due to host being full

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, portainer

I've been using portainer to set up various docker containers and stacks. I recently set up a deluge container, which after being halfway through a large download, threw an error stating that there was no more space left on the machine for saving torrent info.

The stack uses two mounted volumes that point to a mounted CIFS drive of 1TB like so:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  deluge:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest
    container_name: deluge
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - DELUGE_LOGLEVEL=error #optional
    volumes:
      - /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/config:/config
      - /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 8112:8112
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This seemed strange to me since the error was pointing to a file in a `/tmp` directory that was not present in the host machine, so I run the `ls -lh /tmp` command inside the container and found it. From what I understand, since docker is installed inside the host's /var/lib/docker directory, any containers that I set up, will be using the host for any `/tmp` data and in cases such as this, that won't suffice. What are my options here? I tried running `docker-compose up` on the mounted `/mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge` dir, but since it uses the host's docker, it fails with the same issue.

Can I somehow specify to docker (through Portainer preferably) that I want a container to use the storage space on the new mounted drive instead of the space on the host? Would something like adding a mapping to the container's `/tmp` path suffice?

Comment: https://evodify.com/change-docker-storage-location/

Comment: Just add another mount for `/tmp` inside the container. If you're ok with the fact that this data will never be removed automatically, that's all you have to do.

Comment: @anemyte I've thought about that but I also saw that the container seems to also store duplicates of the downloaded files (if they were just links I'm guessing they would not be taking up 40 GB of space, right?). So mounting /tmp or the respective internal directories would be a temporary solution, no? Shouldn't docker use links when using mounted volumes instead of duplicating the files?

Comment: This isn't a temporary solution unless your app never cleans its temporary files. In this case, temporary files will pile up on that mounted drive until you do something about it. As for the duplicates, I never see something like it. Mounts are pretty dumb and work as intended. The common mistake that can possibly lead to something like this is when you mount to somewhere where the app doesn't write to, typically because of a typo or misconfiguration.

Comment: @anemyte I'm very very confused because it seems to me that Deluge IS writing the data on the /mnt/sbox1 mounted CIFS drive but for some reason they take up space on the Host which I can't understand. If i run `ncdu /` there are around 12 GB of data spread across /var (due to docker) &  /usr so I have ~ 25 GB left supposedly, but if I navigate to /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/downloads I can see that around ~25 GB from my 40 GB download have been downloaded and stored there. How is this taking up space on the host though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, I managed to fix it, along with @Pierre B.'s help. It seems like the position of the `vers=3.0` argument matters (I wasn't aware), and after moving it to the left instead of the end of the `fstab` entry, it worked and is now mounting as expected during startup. Here's my `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
//[REDACTED].your-storagebox.de/backup /mnt/sbox1 cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/backup-credentials.txt,iocharset=utf8,uid=www-data,forceuid,gid=root,forcegid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

After editing it, performing a `reboot` or `mount -a` fixed everything up and now `dmesg | grep CIFS` doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can setup your `docker-compose.yml` to mount container's `/tmp` on your large disk, for example:

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  deluge:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest
    container_name: deluge
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - DELUGE_LOGLEVEL=error #optional
    volumes:
      - /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/config:/config
      - /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/downloads:/downloads
      # Mount container's /tmp on large disk
      - /mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge/tmp:/tmp
    ports:
      - 8112:8112
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

> through Portainer preferably

It looks like you're using a `docker-compose.yml` file, in that case I would advise against your container directly in Portainer directly (appart for debugging purposes): any change in your `docker-compose.yml` would re-create container with previous volume definition.

> What are my options here?

Appart from mounting a volume, you can:

- You could change your Docker daemon config to use a folder on your large disk rather than `/var/lib/docker` using [`--data-root` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file), but that seems overly complex for your problem (you would have either to re-install Docker or move all data into new directory)
- Change Deluge's behavior to put temporary files under another directory such as `/downloads/tmp`. But using Docker volume config seems the simpler way in your case, such patterns for mounting `/tmp` are quite common.

EDIT: to answer comment

> it seems to me that Deluge IS writing the data on the /mnt/sbox1 mounted CIFS drive but for some reason they take up space on the Host

Indeed, as you said every Docker container's data is stored under `/var/lib/docker` by default. This will include all data written into your container [writable layer](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) unless they're bind-mounted (volumes will also be created under `/var/lib/docker/volumes`). In other words, everything in your container `/` will be somewhere in `/var/lib/docker/...`.

Your container probably writes somewhere - like `/tmp` and other directories - while downloading, that's why you see such disk usage. You can try to debug while downloading using `du -sh /*` or such in your container to identify disk usage.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Pierre! Sadly, the issue still persists. I actually removed the 20+ GBs of downloaded files from my mounted drive at mnt/sbox1/deluge/downloads and `dfc` now shows that those GBs have been freed on the host as well. I'm completely lost as to how this can be. The mounted drive should be a different storage space that's not tied to the host, no? I'll try something like qbittorrent to see if it's a deluge thing

Comment: Yup, the issue persists even when I'm using qbittorrent

Comment: Oh that may be an issue with your disk partitioning then! It's possible that your `/mnt/sbox1/docker/deluge` directory is actually a sub-mount of small disk `/` instead of your large disk. _The stack uses two mounted volumes that point to a mounted CIFS drive of 1TB_ are you sure about this? Can you show output of `df -h` please?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for helping me through this. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/JmrnLa70. The CIFS drive is mounted using /etc/fstab like so : `//[REDACTED].your-storagebox.de/backup /mnt/sbox1 cifs iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/etc/backup-credentials.txt,x-systemd.automount,uid=1001,gid=1001,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Comment: It seems like the drive isn't even mounted. `dmesg | grep CIFS` prints ```No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[   94.045699] CIFS VFS: Close unmatched open``` despite me having specified `vers=2.1` in the fstab now.

Comment: Odd, it looks like freeing space from your `mnt/sbox/*` drive also free space from your "small" drive. I'm not sure it's related to Docker then, but rather an infra issue from what you tell me. Without further knowledge or access to host in question this would be difficult to diagnose sorry, and may go too far from original question. Maybe identify the mount issue / strange behavior and ask another question? I'm sorry I won't be able to help much more on this :/

Comment: That's my fear as well, I'll have to gather more info and come back with another question. Thank you nonetheless for your time and help, Pierre!

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure ! If you want you can ping me in comment if you create another question, I'll try to help

Comment: Thank you very much, thankfully I managed to fix it during the night yesterday. It seems like the position of the `vers=3.0` argument matters (I wasn't aware), and after moving it to the left instead of the end of the fstab command, it worked and is now mounting as expected during startup :) I've made sure to document all of the errors & fixes that I encountered so hopefully I'll be prepared for the future. I still get the no matching close issue but hopefully that doesn't matter

Comment: Great, can you post that as an answer then?

Comment: Done! Posted it just now :)